# VSCode ssh connection to secondary server

Tags: visual-studio-code, openssh

Cheers,

In order to connect to a secondary server through a primary server, from my own PC, I issue the following command on a Linux terminal:

```
ssh -t user@server1.com ssh user@server2.com
```

How do I use such command chain on VSCode? How do I store it in config file?

Have tried several variations in config file, none of them logged on to server2, but just to server1:

```
Host hostId
     HostName server1
     User user
     LocalCommand ssh -t user@server1.com ssh user@server2.com
```

```
Host hostId
     HostName server1
     User user
     RemoteCommand ssh -t user@server2
```

```
Host hostId
     HostName server1
     User user
     LocalCommand ssh -t user@server2
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

ssh man page indicates the following terminal command also reaches server2 through server1. In other words command drives connection to server2 through a jump ( hence -J ) from server1:

```
ssh -J user server1.com -t user@server2.com
```

As such, the following config directives on VSCode had the same desired result:

```
  Host server2
       ProxyJump user@server1.com   # connect to server1 and jump from it
       HostName server2             # specify server2 and user as usual
       User user
```